# Angular 2 routing issue

Tags: angular, routes

While working with an angular 2 app I encountered this issue when implementing the router system:

> /@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'ROUTER_DIRECTIVES'.)

Noting that I have "@angular/router": "^3.3.1" in package.json

Can I switch to @angular/router 2.0.0 version to fix this error?
If yes; which command shall I use?

Comment: Post your `routing.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

`ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` where gone in RC.6 about half a year ago.

In final you need to add

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes)]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html